# How to Copy to clipboard from extension possible with Clipboard API? (extension running inside an iframe)

Tags: server, tableau-api

Is it possible to copy text from within an extension by clicking on a button? I want to make use of the Clipboard API. Unfortunately, I got some problems because the extension runs inside an iframe.
I have researched the community, but I only found an implementation of a click-to-copy button using the
document.execCommand("copy");
This command was deprecated. Is there a way to include the allow attribute to the iframe tag with "clipboard-write" to enable the clipboard API?
Is it possible at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer on this link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard
Using `execCommand()` we can solve the problem.
Thank you MDN